# How to monkey patch list and dict creation with [] and {}?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class CustomList(list):
    pass


list = CustomList

isinstance(list(), list)
```

This returns True and the following returns False, which should be True.
The `[]` operator is not using my replacement, but the built-in list type. Whenever a list is created using `list()` or `[]`, it should use my `CustomList` class.

```
isinstance([], list)
```

Comment: This is an _astonishingly_ bad idea. This kind of thing is sometimes accepted in the Ruby world, but Python folks tend to follow principle-of-least-surprise, and making code that looks like it's creating a standard list instead create a subclass is _extremely_ surprising.

Comment: out of curiosity, how is this upvoted 5 times? not that its a bad question, its just a bad approach

Comment: You've demonstrated that overwriting the name `list` doesn't change how the list literal works. When you write `[1, 2, 3]` it doesn't call your locally defined class `list([1, 2, 3])`  behind the scenes (which would cause obvious recursion problems).

Comment: @Mark So you cannot change the list literal?

Comment: I know of no way @ConfusedLearner. But I've never had a reason to really explore the idea.

Comment: I think an important question is: what are you trying to solve with your custom list that the built-in list can't do?

Comment: @wholevinski I want to make the list hashable since it is mutable. I am using def __hash__(self): return hash(tuple(sorted(self))). In a nested list with other lists and dictionaries, I would like to solve it that way. Otherwise I would have to call my custom classes everytime.

Comment: There's a good reason the default mutable types aren't hashable. If you change that you'll be breaking a bunch of assumptions and making classes that depend on objects having a consistent hash value throughout their lifetimes behave unpredictably.

Comment: If you want something hashable, use tuples instead of lists.

Comment: If you want to, say, make the JSON decoder create tuples instead of lists, _that_ would be a reasonable question.